# Can Haskell Data Declarations Be Bounded By Type Values

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, declaration

In Haskell, is there a way to limit a data type by the value of its components?  I've drafted an example.  Say you have a checkers game.  A checker is either of the Black or White type.

```
data CheckerType = BlackChecker | WhiteChecker deriving (Eq)

data Checker = Checker CheckerType Int
```

The game board for a checker game contains a set of Black checkers and White checkers.

```
data GameBoard = GameBoard ([Checker]) ([Checker])
```

In the previous declaration, is there any way to enforce the Checkers in the first [Checker] to be of CheckerType black, and the second to be of the opposing type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Positive integer type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910143/positive-integer-type)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest way to do something similar is to parameterize the `Checker` type with what's called a "phantom type":

```
data Black
data White
```

Note that neither of these have any values. They only exist to indicate what color a `Checker` is.

```
data Checker a = Checker Int

data GameBoard = GameBoard [Checker Black] [Checker White]
```

By the way, you don't need those parentheses in the `GameBoard` declaration.

The downside to this approach is that the two colors are now different types, meaning you can't write a function that takes, say, a list of checkers of multiple colors, only a single color.

You could make the phantom types a bit more concrete in order to track allowed colors:

```
data Black = Black
data White = White

data Checker a = Checker a Int

type AnyChecker = Checker (Either Black White)
```

But this can quickly become a lot of hassle to use.

What I suspect you really want is a way to restrict the range of values allowed in one context without making it a completely different type in all contexts. Unfortunately, this isn't really possible in any straightforward fashion in Haskell.

It's a reasonable idea, and some languages do have similar features. Supporting distinctions like this in a generalized way is not simple to add to Haskell's existing type system without collateral damage, though, such as making type inference less robust, even in code not using such a feature.

Comment: If you don't want to do that, one workaround might be stick with your original code, but don't export the `GameBoard` constructor. Instead force users of your module to call a custom constructor that allocates the checkers appropriately, and to update it using functions that maintain the colour allocations.