# Haskell compile time checking of smart constructors

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm learning Haskell, running through the lectures:
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/

I've got:

```
module HanoiDisk(HanoiDisk, hanoiDisk) where
import Control.Exception
data HanoiDisk = HanoiDisk' Integer deriving (Show)
hanoiDisk :: Integer -> HanoiDisk 
hanoiDisk n = assert (n >= 1) $ HanoiDisk' n
```

This works, but if i have:

```
main = do 
  print(show (hanoiDisk (-3))
```

I only get an error during run-time and not at compile-time.

I'm pretty keen to understand how to eliminate run-time exceptions entirely.

Can anyone provide an alternative approach?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What kind of run time error do you encounter?

Comment: `assert` is a runtime check. We can not always make it at compile time -- indeed, what if we call `hanoiDisk` with some data which is only available at runtime? There some techniques that might help here in certain cases (TH, GADTs, dependent types (outside Haskell)) but they are much more advanced. If you are a beginner, I'd recommend to learn the basics of Haskell first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want a way to "fail nicely" when someone applies the function `hanoiDisk` to an argument that's less than 1.

As a commenter stated, doing that at compile time is outside the scope of basic Haskell and you shouldn't need it in your day-to-day code!

You can definitely "fail nicely" by using the `Either a b` datatype.

The idea is that if you have a function `hanoiDisk :: Integer -> HanoiDisk` that takes an `Integer` and is supposed to return a `HanoiDisk` value if the input is "good" and an error value of some sort when the input is "bad", you can encode that using alternate constructors.

The constructors for the `Either a b` datatype are `Left a` and `Right b` where
an error output would be of the form `Left a` and a good output would be of the form `Right b`. Let's rewrite your function using this.

```
hanoiDisk :: Integer -> Either String HanoiDisk 
hanoiDisk n = if n >= 1 
              then Right (HanoiDisk' n)
              else Left "a hanoi disk must be least 1"
```

## (Probably) More Appropriate Answer

Let's discuss the simpler problem of constructing numbers that must be nonnegative (as opposed to positive) in a way that's acceptable to the compiler.

I think the problem is tied to the way numbers are parsed by the compiler. Any time you use the symbols '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', ..., '9' to represent digits in your program the language parser expects the end result to conform to a type like Int, Double, etc. and so when you use these symbols you open yourself up to the possibility that *someone* might prepend a '-' to the sequence of digits and turn your nonnegative number into a negative one.

Let's make a new module called **Natural** which will allow us to create positive numbers. In it, we define "aliases" for the symbols '0',...,'1' using the first two letters of each symbol's name (eg. `tw` for '2'). Since humans write natural numbers using the decimal system, we create a data type called Natural that takes two arguments - the first digit of the number we're representing and then a list of subsequent digits. Finally, we selectively export functions from the module to prohibit "misuse" by users.

```
module Natural (ze,on,tw,th,fo,fi,si,se,ei,ni,Natural(..)) where

newtype Digit = Digit Int

ze = Digit 0
on = Digit 1
tw = Digit 2
th = Digit 3
fo = Digit 4
fi = Digit 5
si = Digit 6
se = Digit 7
ei = Digit 8
ni = Digit 9

data Natural = Nat Digit [Digit]
```

As an example, the natural number 312 would be represented as `Nat th [on,tw]`.

Any module importing **Natural** would only have access to the functions that we export, so attempts to use anything else to define a value of type `Natural` would result in compile errors. Furthermore, since we didn't export the `Digit` constructor there's no way for importers to define their own values for the `Digit` type.

I'm leaving out definitions of the instances for `Num`, `Integral`, `Eq`, `Ord`, etc. because I don't think they would add more to my explanation.

Comment: Ideally, i'd like to find a way to have a compile time exception
For example, if i have
`
data MyString = MyString String
let t = MyString "This is my String" <-- ok
let t = MyString 12321 <-- should raise a compile-time exception
`

There must be _some way_ to have a compile-time exception if someone tries hanoiDisk -1 or hanoiDisk 0

Alternatively, i could try a discriminated union of 
`
HanoiDisk = HanoiDisk' SizeOne | SizeTwo | SizeThree ... SizeTen
`
But i'd like to find an 'unbounded' general solution without the error or maybe monad.

Comment: After some digging I found [a similar question with a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910143/positive-integer-type). The accepted answerer mentions smart constructors, which is what your `HanoiDisk` function is. It also suggests using `Data.Word` which has unsigned integer data types but introduces the problem that `(fromIntegral :: Int -> Word) (-1)` is the same as `maxBound :: Word`. Also, the *exact representations* method mentioned in the answer i.e. `data NonNegative = One | S NonNegative` is kind-of an 'unbounded' general solution.

Comment: a. `_0`,` _1`, ..., `_9` can also be used as the names of digit values. b. `[_0 - _1]` is a valid value under our scheme.

Comment: a. Ah yes I've been extremely silly in that regard, I'll fix that in the answer and credit you. b. Good catch! Implementing `Num Natural` puts us in a fix, doesn't it? Can we only implement `Enum Natural` and then forego having to define `(+)` and `negate` in favor of `fromEnum`?

Comment: I had some typos there, haven't I. :) (it was suppose to be "... under *your* scheme"). The usual thing to do is to define `Nat` as I've shown in the answer. It just can't be negative.  The OP is mainly concerned about the negative arguments, so that would be taken care of automatically. The unary representation is of course inefficient, but we can't have too many of those disks anyway. :)

Comment: I agree that the usual way to do it is according to your answer, but I wanted to sort-of show that the asker's expectations of the language were not in line with the way the language "understands" symbols like 1,2,3... if that makes sense. I would love to be corrected if I have the wrong idea of what the compiler is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer, I knew of the option using an either or maybe monad to fail nicely, but I get distracted by these sorts of questions.
I like your suggestion to alias each of the digits to build our own un-bounded representation.
Another solution a friend suggested was to have lists of null which i quite liked.
Thanks for taking the time to write an answer! :)

Comment: i went with:
`module HanoiDisk(HanoiDisk, hanoiDisk) where`
`data HanoiDisk = HanoiDisk' Fractional deriving (Show)`
`hanoiDisk :: Fractional -> Maybe HanoiDisk`
`hanoiDisk n `
`  | n <= 0 = Nothing`
`  | otherwise = hanoiDisk' n`
I figure it makes sense to consider that a disk has a radius of >0mm
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Haskell checks *types* when compiling a code, not values. To make types depend on values is the job of "dependent types". It is an advanced topic.

The other way to achieve this is to make your `hanoiDisk` work *not* with `Integer`s, but with some "`PositiveInteger`" type which can not possibly be negative (or 0 as well..?). It is a more basic approach.

There will be nothing to assert -- it should be impossible for you to even write down a negative value with this type. You'll have to make this type an instance of `Num`, `Eq`, `Ord`, and `Show` (maybe `Enum` as well).

The usual way is to define

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat 
           deriving (Eq, Show)
```