# haskell higher order function that takes a 'pattern'

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, alias

This leads on from [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298627/haskell-compile-time-checking-of-smart-constructors)

So I have

```
> module HanoiDisk(HanoiDisk, hanoiDisk) where
> data HanoiDisk = HanoiDisk (Maybe Integer) deriving (Show)
> hanoiDisk :: Integer -> HanoiDisk
> hanoiDisk n 
>   | n > 0 = HanoiDisk (Just n)
>   | otherwise = HanoiDisk Nothing
```

I wrote applyMaybe and an infix operator for working with this type:

```
> applyMaybe :: (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
> applyMaybe f (Just a) (Just b) = Just (f a b)
> applyMaybe _ _ _ = Nothing
>
> infix 5 >>>=
> (>>>=) = applyMaybe
```

I wanted to keep applyMaybe and (and the infix) general since this is pretty handy on its own.

But when I try and use applyMaybe with HanoiDisks I get:

```
> a = hanoiDisk 5
> b = hanoiDisk 7
> applyMaybe (>) a b

* Couldn't match expected type `Maybe ()'
              with actual type `HanoiDisk'
* In the third argument of `applyMaybe', namely `b'
  In the expression: applyMaybe (>) a b
  In an equation for `it': it = applyMaybe (>) a b
```

but HanoiDisk is just an alias of Maybe Integer, so this should work?!

---

I realized at the end that 'alias' was the key word, so... instead of using data I used type, I thought I'd be able to answer my own question..

so my module becomes

```
> module HanoiDisk(HanoiDisk, hanoiDisk) where
> type HanoiDisk = Maybe Integer
> hanoiDisk :: Integer -> HanoiDisk
> hanoiDisk n 
>   | n > 0 = (Just n)
>   | otherwise = Nothing
```

Then I can use the general form of my applyMaybe function:

```
> let a = hanoiDisk 4
> let b = hanoiDisk 5
> ((>) >>>= a) b 
Just False
```

I don't like this since you could have

```
> let t = Just (-4)
> expectsGreaterThanZero :: HanoiDisk -> Bool
```

Suggestions? I'm guessing I might have to look at type classes?

Comment: N.b. `applyMaybe f a b = f <$> a <*> b`

Comment: In your first codefragment you write `data HanoiDisk = ...`, in the latter it is `type HanoiDisk = ...`, what did you use?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If your function `>>>=` was applicable to `HanoiDisk`, what would you expect the type of `((>) >>>= a) b` to be?

Comment: `hanoiDisk` was supposed to call `hanoiDisk'`, implementing the actual algorithm. otherwise, this isn't doing anything.

Comment: Do you want a data type for positive integers?

Comment: @AJFarmar: even more directly, `applyMaybe = liftA2`. The latter is now actually a method of `Applicative`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have correctly determined, the reason for the original error message is that:

```
data HanoiDisk = HanoiDisk (Maybe Integer)
```

introduces an "algebraic data type" and not a "type alias", so the values of `a` and `b` are of type `HanoiDisk` not `Maybe Integer`  The type error then results because the type `HanoiDisk` is not of the form `Maybe a` and/or `Maybe b` required by `applyMaybe`.

One way of accomplishing what you want -- having a general `applyMaybe` operate on types that aren't `Maybe a` but somehow "look" like the pattern `Maybe a` -- is to introduce a typeclass, but to paraphrase an old joke about regular expressions:  "A new Haskell programmer has a problem and decides to use a type class.  Now the programmer has two problems."  Ha ha!

#### Just convert it

I've included a type class solution below, but the more straightforward and idiomatic way of treating `HanoiDisk` like a `Maybe Integer` is to provide a conversion function, either explicitly or by introducing a named field in the data type, as below.  This approach is used throughout the standard library, and in real world Haskell code.

```
module HanoiDiskConvert where

data HanoiDisk = HanoiDisk { getHanoiDisk :: Maybe Integer }
  deriving (Show)
hanoiDisk :: Integer -> HanoiDisk
hanoiDisk n
  | n > 0 = HanoiDisk (Just n)
  | otherwise = HanoiDisk Nothing

applyMaybe :: (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
applyMaybe f (Just a) (Just b) = Just (f a b)
applyMaybe _ _ _ = Nothing
-- or as noted below, just: applyMaybe = liftA2

main = do
  let a = hanoiDisk 5
      b = hanoiDisk 7
  print $ applyMaybe (>) (getHanoiDisk a) (getHanoiDisk b)
```

You should think of `getHanoiDisk` as being the moral equivalent of having to use `fromIntegral` when you write `mean xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)`.  It's just satisfying Haskell's requirement that even "obvious" type conversions should be explicit.

A further advantage of this approach is that -- as referenced in a comment -- `Maybe` already has an `Applicative` instance that you can be using here.  Your `applyMaybe` is just a specialization of `liftA2` from `Control.Applicative`:

```
import Control.Applicative
applyMaybe :: (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
applyMaybe = liftA2
```

and there's a bunch of other useful stuff in that module that you can use.  For example, the following are equivalent, and the applicative operator syntax becomes easy to read and write as you gain experience using it:

```
applyMaybe (>) (getHanoiDisk a) (getHanoiDisk b)
(>) <$> getHanoiDisk a <*> getHanoiDisk b      -- using applicative operators
```

#### An ill-advised typeclass solution

Anyway, if you *really* wanted to do this using a type class, it would look something like this.  You'd define a class that allows conversion of a "maybe-like" type to and from an actual maybe value:

```
class MaybeLike m a | m -> a where
  toMaybe :: m -> Maybe a
  fromMaybe :: Maybe a -> m
```

You'd also want to define an instance to allow plain `Maybe` values themselves to be treated as maybe-like!

```
instance MaybeLike (Maybe a) a where
  toMaybe = id
  fromMaybe = id
```

Then, you could define an instance for your `HanoiDisk` type:

```
data HanoiDisk = HanoiDisk (Maybe Integer) deriving (Show)
instance MaybeLike HanoiDisk Integer where
  toMaybe (HanoiDisk x) = x
  fromMaybe x = HanoiDisk x
```

Finally, you can define a general `applyMaybe` that can work with any `MaybeLike` types, by converting to and from `Maybe`:

```
applyMaybe :: (MaybeLike m a, MaybeLike n b, MaybeLike k c)
           => (a -> b -> c) -> m -> n -> k
applyMaybe f m n = fromMaybe $ f <$> toMaybe m <*> toMaybe n
```

Finally, then, this would allow you to write the full program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

module HanoiClass where

class MaybeLike m a | m -> a where
  toMaybe :: m -> Maybe a
  fromMaybe :: Maybe a -> m

instance MaybeLike (Maybe a) a where
  toMaybe = id
  fromMaybe = id

data HanoiDisk = HanoiDisk (Maybe Integer) deriving (Show)
instance MaybeLike HanoiDisk Integer where
  toMaybe (HanoiDisk x) = x
  fromMaybe x = HanoiDisk x

applyMaybe :: (MaybeLike m a, MaybeLike n b, MaybeLike k c)
           => (a -> b -> c) -> m -> n -> k
applyMaybe f m n = fromMaybe $ f <$> toMaybe m <*> toMaybe n

hanoiDisk :: Integer -> HanoiDisk
hanoiDisk n
  | n > 0 = HanoiDisk (Just n)
  | otherwise = HanoiDisk Nothing

main = do
  let a = hanoiDisk 5
      b = hanoiDisk 7
      res = applyMaybe (>) a b :: Maybe Bool
  print res
```

#### But you shouldn't be doing this...

Work through and play with the above code if you like, but realize that it's a terrible idea for an actual design.  One reason is that I can see right now that your choice of representation for `HanoiDisk` isn't a good one.  This may start to become obvious to you when you switch from writing generic functions and type classes and try to solve your actual programming problem.  For example, you might write:

```
data HanoiTower = HanoiTower [HanoiDisk]
```

and start asking yourself what this value represents:

```
HanoiTower [HanoiDisk (Just 3), HanoiDisk Nothing]
```

and why you're writing code to handle it.  Then, you'll start to wonder, why were you ever trying to compare a `HanoiDisk (Just 3)` with a `HanoiDisk Nothing`?  When would this ever be useful?

Finally, you'll realize that you really want to check for and act on valid disk sizes at the *start* of your program but work internally with a representation of valid disks only:

```
newtype HanoiDisk' = HanoiDisk' Integer
```

that have either been created by an alternate smart constructor:

```
hanoiDisk' :: Integer -> Maybe HanoiDisk'
hanoiDisk' n | n > 0 = Just (HanoiDisk' n)
             | otherwise = Nothing
```

or by other code that "obviously" creates valid disks.

At this point you'll also realize that all the time you spent writing type classes, instances, and generic `applyMaybe` functions was wasted.

If you'd stuck with a more agile design with a couple of `getHanoiDisk` calls sprinkled around, you'd have a lot less useless code to abandon.

If you're coming from a Java background or something, you're probably used to the idea of developing elaborate boilerplate, object hierarchies, and best-practice design patterns on the front end before you write your first line of useful code.  This can be an effective approach in the Java universe, but it's less effective in programming Haskell, especially when you're just starting out.

Though it will be difficult, try making a conscious effort to write the most straightforward code you can, and don't look so hard for artificial opportunities to catch non-positive numbers at compile time, write generic higher-order functions, and introduce type classes to solve every problem.  These opportunities will evolve naturally in a way they seldom do when writing in other programming languages.  This is advice I wish someone had hammered into my head five years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reply! :) Yeah I'm over cooking the problem, I guess I'm trying to explore the language find the right pattern to solve common problems. I can picture using smart constructors a lot, but wanting to use those with generic functions.