# Data constructor with compile-time constraints in haskell

Tags: haskell, constructor, constraints

If I'm trying to define an RGB type constructor, I have something like this:

```
data RGBColor = RGBColor int int int deriving Show
```

However, I'd like to bound these in valid values between 0 and 255.  At first, it seems like maybe I can typeclass my ints

```
data SafeRGBColor = SafeRGBColor Eightbit Eightbit Eightbit deriving Show
```

That is, I can now just define something called Eightbit that will do the validation for me.  But that just seems to kick the can down the road. When I think about how to specify that:

```
type Eightbit = Int -- ...?   0 to 255?
```

Unclear!  What's the correct, idiomatic way to add constraints to my custom data type?

### Update

I appreciate the tips to word8, but I was really looking for the generic answer on this, RGB colors just being one example of a kind of constraint.

I would prefer to have more information about how to catch these constraints at compile-time versus at runtime which the example this is called a duplicate of emphasizes.

Comment: don't reinvent the byte, try Word8 from Data.Word package.

Comment: Neat.  That does solve my problem.  

```Prelude Data.List Data.Word> 0 :: Word8
0
Prelude Data.List Data.Word> 255 :: Word8
255
Prelude Data.List Data.Word> 256 :: Word8

<interactive>:85:1: warning: [-Woverflowed-literals]
    Literal 256 is out of the Word8 range 0..255
0
```

Ok, but for learning in general, what's the way I'd do this if I had to reinvent the constraints I had?

Comment: And see also [Positive integer type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11910143/791604).

Answer (score 2):

don't reinvent the byte, try Word8 from Data.Word package.

alternatively, using smart constructors

```
mkEightbit :: Int -> Eightbit Int
mkEightbit n | n < 0 || n > 255 = error "invalid value" 
             | otherwise        = Eightbit n
```

or, use mod 256 to eliminate error state.

Comment: "Smart constructors" was a very helpful term to understand what I was looking for.  Thank you!  It would be awesome to get it all compile-time, but man the stuff on Phantom Types and Peano Numbers here was a bit dense for me: https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors