# How to enforce type relation and constraints when defing data type

Tags: haskell

In the following code:

```
data Point = Point { x           :: Int, 
                     leftHeight  :: Int, 
                     rightHeight :: Int}
data Rectangle = Rec Point Point

rec1 = Rec p1 p2
```

There are several constraints when creating `Rec` such as:

```
x p1 < x p2
(leftHeight p1 ) should always be zero
(rightHeight p2 ) should always be zero
rightHeight p1 == leftHeight p2
```

Is there a way to enforce these constraints at type level?
Because I'm using `QuickCheck` to generate some sample `Rec` but these contraints make `QuickCheck` very slow to generate random samples.

edit: I've solved the slow QuickCheck issue. But anyway still curious if such constraint can be expressed in Haskell

Comment: This may be an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). **a)** not every constraint can be feasibly expressed in Haskell. Haskell is not Agda; if you want full type safety all the way  down than that or some other dependently-typed language is what you should use. But it's perfectly possible to _informally_ enforce such properties in Haskell: just make sure all the functions you export from your module ensure these properties. **b)** if QuickCheck is too slow, then this may be what you should ask about. I suspect you use a generate&discard scheme?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910143/positive-integer-type/11912348#11912348

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To point out the obvious, the standard way of enforcing these constraints at type level would be to define your `Rectangle` differently:

```
data Rectangle = Rec
  { x1 :: Int
  , x2 :: Int
  , height :: Int
  }
```

This enforces all constraints except "x1 < x2".  You can use smart destructors to recreate the rectangle's `Point` "fields":

```
point1 :: Rectangle -> Point
point1 (Rec x1 _ h) = Point x1 0 h

point2 :: Rectangle -> Point
point2 (Rec _ x2 h) = Point x2 h 0
```

and define a smart constructor (which can also enforce the "x1 < x2" constraint):

```
rect :: Point -> Point -> Rectangle
rect (Point x1 0 h1) (Point x2 h2 0) | h1 == h2 && x1 < x2 = Rec x1 x2 h1
rect _ _ = error "bad rectangle"
```

Seriously, this really is the best way to enforce constraints at the type level in Haskell!

Comment: Importantly, don't export `Rec`! Or, if you do, make sure it's documented as "unsafe," and preferably only export it from a different (`Unsafe` or `Internal` or ...)  module. Otherwise, it all falls apart.