# Haskell Type Level Constraint

Tags: haskell, type-constraints

I'm curious if it's possible to write something like this (pseudo code) in Haskell:

```
data Clock = Clock {hour :: (0 <= Int <= 24),  minutes :: (0 <= Int <= 60)}
```

to make impossible (at the type level) to create something like this:

```
let a = Clock 34 236
```

Or should one use a kind of Clock builder which will check and create a valid Clock time?

Comment: You can work with *LiquidHaskell*: https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-blog/

Comment: strictly speaking you can of course define two types `data Hour = HOne | HTwo | ... | HTwentyThree` and `data Minute = MOne | MTwo | ... | MFiftyNine`, and then define clock as `Clock { hour :: Hour, minutes :: Minute }`.

Comment: See also [Positive integer type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11910143/791604), which discusses various approaches that would also be relevant here and their tradeoffs. Not a duplicate, though, I think, as @WillemVanOnsem's solution is not listed there.

Comment: By the way, I think the upper bounds should not be inclusive: `< 24` and `< 60`.

Comment: The time is 24:60 and you're listening to Ẓ̸̼̝̞̪͈̣́A̵̭͒L̵̨̛̰̪͎̈̃̈́̑̚͝G̵͇̲͓̠̜͈̈́̓̌̚͠O̴͖͇̥͑̌͌̈́͌ͅ ̷̡̛̳̳̟̱̳̦͘̕r̵̖̅͌̐a̸̡̝͑͝d̷͖͔̋̈͋̔͂̈́͝i̵̢̮̣͐͑͐̋͒ỗ̷̲̇

Answer (score 7):

The concrete example is best expressed with types from the [modular-arithmetic package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/modular-arithmetic-2.0.0.1/docs/Data-Modular.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, TypeFamilies, DataKinds #-}

import Data.Modular

data Clock = Clock {hour :: Int/24,  minutes :: Int/60}
```

Note that the upper bounds are *exclusive* here, as you should have probably had in your code as well.

Modular arithmetic is a special case of a [quotient type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_type), which is in some ways more practical than *constrained* types. But Haskell has no general, direct support for either. As Willem Van Onsen mentioned, Liquid Haskell adds such functionality. Can't say much about that, but I've heard multiple times that it works surprisingly well.

Comment: And, to be explicit: `/` uses the technique proposed in the question, namely, using a kind of builder that will check and create a valid modular value. (The jargon for this is "smart constructor".)

Answer (score 7):

### Smart constructors

One simple way to do this is to use smart encapsulation and smart constructors:

```hs
module HoursAndMinutes (Hours, mkHours, getHours, Minutes, mkMinutes, getMinutes) where

newtype Hours = UnsafeHours Int

mkHours :: Int -> Maybe Hours
mkHours n | 0 <= n && n < 24 = Just (UnsafeHours n)
          | otherwise = Nothing

getHours :: Hours -> Int
getHours (UnsafeHours n) = n

newtype Minutes = UnsafeMinutes Int

mkMinutes :: Int -> Maybe Minutes
mkMinutes n | 0 <= n && n < 60 = Just (UnsafeMinutes n)
            | otherwise = Nothing

getMinutes :: Minutes -> Int
getMinutes (UnsafeMinutes n) = n
```

Now in your other code if you import `HoursAndMinutes` then you cannot construct invalid `Hours` or `Minutes`.

```hs
data Clock = Clock {hours :: Hours,  minutes :: Minutes}
```

Then this will result in `Nothing`:

```
Clock <$> mkHours 34 <*> mkMinutes 236
```

### Refined

You can use the built-in predicates from [`refined`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/refined-0.6.2) package to simplify this approach slightly:

```hs
data Clock = Clock
  { hours   :: Refined (FromTo 0 23) Int
  , minutes :: Refined (FromTo 0 59) Int
  }
```

Then you can construct one with:

```
Clock <$> refine 34 <*> refine 236
```

Which will be `Left (RefineSomeException ...)`.

The disadvantage is still that the checks are at runtime. You can get compile time checks by using Template Haskell:

```
Clock $$(refineTH 34) $$(refineTH 236)
```

This will throw an exception at compile time.

### Liquid Haskell

You can make this more convenient by using [Liquid Haskell](https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-blog/) as Willem van Onsem suggests in his comment:

```hs
module Clock where

data Clock = Clock { hours :: Int, minutes :: Int } deriving Show
{-@ data Clock = Clock
      { hours   :: {h:Int | 0 <= h && h < 24}
      , minutes :: {m:Int | 0 <= m && m < 60}
      } @-}

goodClock :: Clock
goodClock = Clock 16 49

badClock :: Clock
badClock = Clock 34 236 -- this gives an error
```

[Try it out here](http://goto.ucsd.edu:8090/index.html#?demo=permalink%2F1626727781_37355.hs).

Comment: Thank you very much. Liquid haskell looks very clean and intuitive. I will study this library. I am also tempted by the comonad builder pattern but it looks as a quite heavy solution.