# Does a type Int in the range of 1 <= x <= 255 exist?

Tags: haskell

I would like to create the following declaration:

```hs
data Color = B | W deriving Read

type Cell = (Color, Int) where 1 <= Int <= 255
```

Is there any solution to this problem ? The type, as it is, accepts any `Int` but those outside that range shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite, but if you `import Data.Word`, there is the type [`Word8`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Word.html#t:Word8).

This is an "8-bit unsigned integer type", so its values range from 0-255, rather than 1-255 as you wished.

If that is not suitable for you, then the techniques in the answers to [the question Noughtmare referred to in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68445787/haskell-type-level-constraint) are additional things to consider.

Answer (score 4):

1-to-255 is a pretty unusual range. Fairly sure this doesn't exist as such in any library. Are you sure you don't want 0-to-255? In that case, `Word8` can be used.

For arbitrary upper bounds (but always 0 as the lower), there is [`Finite` from the finite-typelis package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/finite-typelits-0.1.6.0/docs/Data-Finite-Internal.html#v:Finite).

In *general*, what you would typically do to express constraints on a type's values is to introduce a custom newtype wrapper. In doubt, I would actually select `Int` as the number type – it's way overkill in terms of bit count, but there's not much to be won by selecting something smaller because Haskell boxed values anyway involve an Int-sized pointer. Meanwhile it's still more efficient than `Integer`.

So,

```
newtype CellI = CellI { getCellI :: Int -- ^ In range [1,255]
                      }

mkCellI :: Int -> Maybe CellI
mkCellI n
 | n>=1, n<=255  = Just (CellI n)
 | otherwise     = Nothing
```

Of course, such a wrapper is in some ways awkward. An alternative is to not express the invariant in Haskell at all, but simply use an ordinary `Int` and then [Liquid Haskell](https://liquid.kosmikus.org/01-intro.html#/more-precise-types) for expressing the exact range. This is much more concise for a constraint like range-of-int than if you mess about with pseudo-dependent Haskell.

Comment: I appreciate this answer so much ! Upvoted. Could you tell me how can you use a comma in the guard ?

Comment: Could you tell me why do you use `newtype` instead of `data` ?

Comment: You should generally use `newtype` unless you have a specific reason to use `data`. The latter incurs one extra thunk indirection, which normally means it's both slower and less memory-efficient.

Comment: It also means it is representationally equal to the underlying `Int` at runtime, so you can derive various instances for it `newtype Cell = Cell Int deriving newtype (Eq, Ord, Num, ..)`.