# Sum of cubes of positive integers of list using recursion (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a short Haskell function to compute the sum of the cubes of all positive integers in a list using recursion.

```
f'' :: [Int] -> Int
f''[] = 0
f'' (x:xs) =  (x^3 + f''(xs))
```

But I can't figure out how to ensure only positive values of x are accepted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positive integer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910143/positive-integer-type)

Comment: do you want to compute only positive integers or you want the list to have only positives. Meaning: `f'' [-1, 2, 3] \`shouldBe\` 2^3 + 3^3` or `f'' [-1, 2, 3] \`shouldBe\` failure!`

Comment: @mkrieger1 Hmm I think I just figured it out, had to make a guarded function.

Comment: @Ismor Compute only positives

Comment: I don't think it's getting any shorter than `f'' = sum . map (^3) . filter (>0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter, with guards, so then the function will look like:

```
f'' :: [Int] -> Int
f'' [] = 0
f'' (x:xs)
  | x > 0 = x^3 + f''(xs)
  | otherwise = …
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` part.